# Immutability property in java

Tags: java, immutability, final

I know that when it comes to passing objects in java, the reference of object is passed as value. So what ever changes you make to that object is reflected in the original object as well. To avoid this we make use of immutability property in java.

So my question is, I have created an **immutable** class `Employee`, When I pass an object of this `Employee` class to some method in other class, I don't want that method to make any changes to this object. Even if it does, I don't want the changes to be affected to the original object created in the calling class.

Here is my sample code.

```
public final class Employee {
    int employeeId;

    public int getId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.employeeId = id;
    }

}

public class Worker {
    public static void process(Employee f, Employee g){
        int c = f.getId();
        f.setId(g.getId());
        g.setId(c);
    }
}

public class ImmutabilityTest{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee teamMember = new Employee();
        Employee teamLead = new Employee();
        teamMember.setId(5);
        teamLead.setId(10);
        System.out.println("Before process "+teamMember.getId() + " " + teamLead.getId());
        Worker.process(teamMember, teamLead);
        System.out.println("After process "+teamMember.getId() + " " + teamLead.getId());
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
Before process 5 10
After process 10 5
```

Is there any way to avoid the change in the values of the member variables of the Employee class ? (apart from making them `final`)If not then how are we actually exploiting the **Immutability** property in java in user defined class ?

Any suggestions/opinions/pointers are appreciated ! Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Immutability is not a property in Java that can be applied to an Object with a single keyword, its a strategy that needs to be implemented on a case by case basis. Generally speaking, you utilize the `final` keyword and cloning in order to accomplish this. Note that the deeper your object nesting, the greater the level of difficulty in achieving true object immutability.

Here is a (more) immutable version of your Employee class:

```
public class Employee {
    final int employeeId;

    public Employee(final int id) {
        super();
        this.employeeId = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
}
```

Note that reflection in Java makes it practically impossible to achieve true immutability, even with the use of the final instance variables and cloning.

Answer (score 4):

`Employee` has a setter *and* has a non-private field, therefore it is **not** [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

Remove the setter, and make the field `private`, and your problem is solved.

Your other option is to pass a *copy* of the object (typically using a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) to create it)

Comment: even if I remove the setter, it doesn't make any difference. I can still change the value like `teamMember.id=15`

Answer (score 1):

You could change the visibility of the `setId` method to be package private, and make sure that `Worker` is in a different package to `Employee`.

Alternatively remove the `setId` method entirely.

> [If the other class makes changes] I don't want the changes to be affected to the original object created in the calling class.

If you want to take that approach, then you need to create and pass a *copy* of the original object.

---

Note that unless you declare the private `employeeId` field to be `final`, you won't get the full benefit of immutability.  Strictly speaking, the `getId` method needs to be synchronized if there is any possibility that different threads will call `getId` on the same `Employee` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the *final* keyword to a class simply indicates that the class can not be extended (or sub-classed).

It has nothing to do with whether or not its members can be modified.

Comment: +1: Thanks for correction, I got mixed up with String class being final and immutable !! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you Don't want someone to change your properties value, you can keep them as private without setter.